# Angular CLI + npm + prebuild

Tags: angular, npm, build, angular-cli

I've an angular 2 project (that uses npm) created with angluar-cli.

I'd like to copy a folder in a another folder before each compilation.
the idea is have multiple theme (multiple folders) and copy one of theme ( choosen via a variable 'themeId' ).

Is it possible ?

- how to execute a copy script before each compilation ( the script has to work on windows or linux!) ?
- how to set a param themeId argument passed to this script and how to set the default value of this variable if not set ?

Thx in advance.

Comment: You can use gulp.js which does exactly what you want, plus some cool features.

Answer (score 2):

now i use nodejs script executed in npm scripts conf (package.json) and use environnement variables using --projectname:client=client1

HERE SOME PART OF MY package.json

```
 "config": {
  //default value
  "client": "client0"
}

 "scripts": {

//link to nodejs file who's using process.env.npm_package_config_client variable
   "prestart": "node inoscripts/copyfiles.js",
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e"
}
```